# how show properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I have to show some rocks thats belongs to cave and cave belongs to user! well seems fair enough right? but why the rocks show page sill don't recognize the cave? here we go:

**rock model**

```
belongs_to :cave
```

**cave model**

```
has_many :rocks
```

**user model**

```
has_one :cave
```

**rock controller**

```
def new 
    @rock = Rock.new
  end

    def show
     @cave = Cave.find(params[:cave_id])
       @rock = @cave.rocks
    end

  def create  
    @rock = current_user.cave.rocks.build(params[:rock]) 
    if @rock.save
      flash.now[:success] = "Ya Man"
      redirect_to :action => :show
    else
      render :new    
  end
end
```

**rock show view**

```
<h2><%= @rock.cave.name %></h2>
```

**error**

```
undefined method `cave' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: `@ock = current_user.cave.rocks.build(params[:rock])` - here you forgot `r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `show` action, `@cave.rocks` is returning nil, so you assign nil to `@rock`. By the way, I guess it returns a collection and you wouldn't have a rock element there, you might want to use `@cave.rocks.first` instead.

Also, it's rather weird to have a show action on rocks controller that takes the cave id and finds the rock based on it. A more standard approach would be to receive the rock id.

Comment: so i have to assign nil to @rock? but this was not suppose to just show by id?

Comment: no, I'm just describing what you're doing. With your current code, you don't get anything saved in the db? if you do, then you should use `@rock = @cave.rocks.first` (if you want to get the first one; add existence checking)

Comment: yeah i got, everything is working fine excepts to show the cave name on the rocks show!

Comment: yeah thank's Marcelo, now i understood how this associated show action  works :)

Answer (score 1):

On the show action, in your line:

```
@rock = @cave.rocks
```

You are assigning (probably) an ActiveRelation to the variable @rock. `cave.rocks` will return the collection of rocks belonging to that cave.

You could call `@rock = @cave.rocks.first` but the normal practice in a view would be to show all rocks associated with a cave, not just the first.

Comment: humm! ahh thx, now i got the idea! but if i'm just show the cave name, so i have just to assign the user cave on the rocks show action right?